# Is is posible to filter group of records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table with operations on vehicle. It looks like this:

| idr | idp | ope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2230530165347004000299104100 | 2230530164734003000299104 | 8 |
| 2230530165330003000299104100 | 2230530164734003000299104 | 14 |
| 2230530164818004000299104100 | 2230530164734003000299104 | 1 |
| 2230530164734033000299104100 | 2230411105828003005269783 | 2 |
| 2230530163656012000290160100 | 2230411105828003005269783 | 14 |
| 2230530163614017000290160100 | 2230411105828003005269783 | 1 |

idr - unique identifier

idp - id of the vehicle, every vehicle have own idp, top 3 records are for one vehicle and other 3 records are from other vehicle

ope - operation number, every type of operation have own ope number, for example 1 = First registration 14 - order vehicle document, 8 - release document, 2 - deregistration etc

I want to find every vehicle that has ope 132 but at the same time doesn't have ope 131. For example:

- No. 1 vehicle Audi A4 with idp 2230530160651002000290160 and this vehicle has operations 1, 14, 8, 132, 131
- No. 2 vehicle BMW M5 with idp 2230530160537003000291185 and this vehicle has operations 1, 14, 8, 132

I need only vehicles like vehicle no. 2.

I tried using union, cte, group by but my knowledge is insufficient to make query like this. Every time query result contains vehicles with ope 131.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match your sample data, could you update your post to fix that? Also, add the output you expect.

Comment: @ahmed Why? in his example the results set would be empty. it works lol

Comment: @DougCoats Yes, it would be, but the explanations used to be based on the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find every vehicle that has ope 132 but at the same time doesn't have ope 131

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select idp
from mytable
where ope in (131, 132)
group by idp
having min(ope) = 132
```

The query fiters on both operation, and ensures that 131 does not occur (since the minimum value is 132).

A more generic approach uses `case` expressions (this would fit more complex cases, over more columns):

```
select idp
from mytable
where ope in (131, 132)                              -- any of the two operations
group by idp
having max(case when ope = 131 then 1 else 0) = 0    -- 131 was not found
   and max(case when ope = 132 then 1 else 0) = 1    -- but 132 was found
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a pretty rough example. Your checking for presence of your first criteria in the outer query and the absence of the 2nd in your inner query.

```
SELECT distinct idp 
FROM Yourtable yt1
WHERE ope IN (132)
AND not exists
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT idp
        FROM yourTable yt2
        WHERE open IN (131)
        AND yt2.idp = yt1.idp
    )
```